# What is the meaning of CONTEXT_CONTROL when working with CONTEXT structure in Windows C programming?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

So i have seen many codes that use CONTEXT keyword to for example store a context of a thread in Windows

for example :

```
CONTEXT threadContext;
threadContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;
GetThreadContext(threadHandle , &threadContext)
```

i have seen this in some blogposts and a book about hijacking threads but no where they explain what is this ContextFlags and CONTEXT_CONTROL

can someone explain to me what these are in a simple term and why it was needed to add the second line when trying to get a context of a thread??

because even in resuming the thread it is used:

```
threadContext.Eip = (DWORD)remoteCave;
threadContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;
SetThreadContext(threadHandle , &threadContext);
ResumeThread(threadHandle);
```

Comment: They fumbled the current MSDN article, the old one had the proper advice.  Quoting: "Refer to the header file WinNT.h for definitions of this structure for each processor architecture."  Which is good advice, it thoroughly documents what the various context flags means and what specific registers are affected.  CONTEXT_CONTROL is minimal, it only records the stack and instruction pointer registers but not the floating point processor, general purpose, extended and debugging registers.

Comment: look in *winnt.h* - *CONTEXT_CONTROL specifies SegSs, Rsp, SegCs, Rip, and EFlags.* for x64, *CONTEXT_CONTROL specifies Sp, Lr, Pc, and Cpsr* for arm *specifies FP, LR, SP, PC, and CPSR* for arm64,

Comment: and *SS:SP, CS:IP, FLAGS, BP* for x86 - all written in winnt.h (eip, ebp, esp of course, simply copy-paste as is in winnt.h)

Comment: The value of the ContextFlags member of this structure specifies which portions of a thread's context are retrieved